# how to pause/resume a fleet unit?

Tags: coreos, etcd

I have a vagrant coreos cluster setup in my computer. I could submit, load, start, stop, unload, destroy fleet units in different hosts in cluster. Are there fleetctl commands for pause/resume a unit that already been loaded/started? If there is no inbuilt command, how to achieve pause/resume functionality of fleet units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Containers are supposed to be stateless, and you should design your app that way.

However if you want to pause, you can connect to the host running your unit and use `docker pause`/`unpause`.

Or if you never want to stop your container, tweak your unit file using wrapper scripts this way :

```
    [Unit]
    Description=blah

    [Service]
    ExecStart=<full path>/start.sh
    ExecStop=<full path>/stop.sh
```

start.sh script :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ $(docker ps|grep <CONTAINER NAME/ID> == "" ]]; then
        docker start <yourname>/<yourcontainer>
    else
        docker unpause <CONTAINER NAME/ID>
    fi
```

stop.sh script :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ $(docker ps|grep <CONTAINER NAME/ID> == "" ]]; then
        echo "container not running"
    else
        docker pause <CONTAINER NAME/ID>
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this in fleet today. My question is, how is pause/resume and different than stop/start or destroy/start?

Comment: pause means unit is suspended with its state. resume is to wakeup the unit from suspend state. start/stop kills the units and restarts it.